# Crop Images (category Image) on own templates

Tags: image, category

I create a new template in Magento. On that I'll get the Image-Output with this code.

```
<div class="worlds-image">
  <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$categoryImage  ?>" />
</div>
```

How can I crop that image with max-width of 250px and keep the image ratio as well?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to resize image

> Mage::helper('catalog/image')->resize($imageUrl, $width , $height)